# How do I get a list of all open programs

Tags: windows, batch-file, process

I am using batch on windows 7 and I want to store the list of all open programs in a variable.
I have tried tasklist and wmic but the list includes the backend processes.

What I am searching for is the list of all the applications started by the user.

Any idea ?

Thanks,
SLP

Comment: How would you define that? By the program having a visible window? How? See https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/05/winlistexe-list-open-windows-and-their.html for ideas.

Comment: I want to get the list on the tab "Applications" when you do ctrl+alt+supr, not the list in the tab "processus"

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20171219-00/?p=97606

Comment: Processes, regardless of their visibility, are applications and programs. I'm going to suggest that there is no robust method of determining one from the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a close approximation to that tab, but its bot going to be perfect.

Let me start out with a few other options.

Services themselves always run under session 0, even if they are running as a given user.

In case you want the processes and services run by or as  the current user you are logged on with:

```
Tasklist -/FI "USERNAME -eq %Username%" /V
```

If you just want to exclude services and see all processes (and not services) running as any user logged into the system use this:

```
Tasklist -/FI "SESSION -gt 0" /V
```

If you want to see only processes that are not services, and only for the current use you can use:

```
Tasklist -/FI "USERNAME -eq %Username%" /FI "SESSION -gt 0"  /V
```

### A fairly close approximation of the Application tab:

For a close approximation of the applications tab however we only want windows running as the current user wirh window tirles.

```
Tasklist -/FI "USERNAME -eq %Username%" /FI "SESSION -gt 0"  /V | FIND /I /V " N/A"
```

Unfortunately windows without titles can also be running but they should have a blank instead of an N/A, of course it's possible to have a window running wirh N/A as its title too; and some processes not listed in the applications tab can have window titles; further there can be items showing in the Application tab that are modules of a process, such as modal windows like the reminder window on outlook, and other items such as searches in explorer which would just show up n/a.

So this isn't perfect, but often its a close enough approximation.